# java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input

Tags: x509certificate, javacard, apdu

I have a certificate in my javacard applet which the host application requests to verify challenges from the host application signed by the card applet:

1. The host application computes challenges for the javacard applet to sign as follows.

   ```
           byte [] card_signature=null;
           SecureRandom random = SecureRandom . getInstance( "SHA1PRNG" ) ;
           byte [ ]bytes = new byte [ 20 ] ;
           random . nextBytes ( bytes) ;
           CommandAPDU challenge;
           ResponseAPDU resp3;
           challenge =  new CommandAPDU(IDENTITY_CARD_CLA,SIGN_CHALLENGE, 0x00, 0x00,bytes ,20 );
           resp3= c.transmit(challenge);
           if(resp3.getSW()==0x9000) {
               card_signature = resp3.getData();
                                   String s= DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(card_signature);
               System.out.println("signature: " + s);
           }else System.out.println("Challenge signature error " + resp3.getSW());
   ```
2. The javacard applet signs the host application challenges and sends back the signature  as follows:

   ```
   private void sign(APDU apdu) {
   if(!pin.isValidated())ISOException.throwIt(SW_PIN_VERIFICATION_REQUIRED);
   else{
       byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
       byte [] output = new byte [64];
       short length = 64;
       short x =0;     
       Signature signature =Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_RSA_SHA_PKCS1, false);
       signature.init(privKey, Signature.MODE_SIGN);
       short sigLength = signature.sign(buffer, offset,length, output, x);
       //This sequence of three methods sends the data contained in
       //'serial' with offset '0' and length 'serial.length'
       //to the host application.
       apdu.setOutgoing();
       apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)output.length);
       apdu.sendBytesLong(output,(short)0,(short)output.length);
   }
   }
   ```
3. To verify the javacard applet signature, the host requests the javacard applet certificate from the javacard. The certificate (as a byte array) is 256 bytes and I gather it can only be sent in blocks of lenghth 240. The javacard applet sends the certificate as follows:

   ```
   private void send_certificate (APDU apdu) {  
           if(!pin.isValidated())ISOException.throwIt(SW_PIN_VERIFICATION_REQUIRED);
           else{


               apdu.setOutgoing();
               apdu.setOutgoingLength((short)240);
               apdu.sendBytesLong(certificate,(short)0,(short)240);
           }

       }
   ```
4. The host application then receives the certificate in bytes and constructs the certificate. In addition, it attempts to verify signed challenges with the certificate as follows:

   ```
   //Get certificate
   CommandAPDU card_cert;
           ResponseAPDU resp4;
           card_cert =  new CommandAPDU(IDENTITY_CARD_CLA, SEND_CERTIFICATE, 0x00, 0x00);
           resp4 = c.transmit(card_cert);
           if(resp4.getSW()==0x9000) {
               byte [] response = resp4.getData();
               String certf= DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(response);
               System.out.println("CERTIFICATE: " + certf);


           CertificateFactory certFac = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

           InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(response);            
            X509Certificate cert = ( X509Certificate ) certFac .generateCertificate( is ) ;

            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            signature.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());
           signature.update(card_signature);
           if(card_signature !=null) {
           boolean ok =signature.verify(card_signature);
           if(ok==true)System.out.println("verification completed" );

           }

       }
   ```

I get the error below:

```
signature: 802800001438BBAE2CE7AD2498B0A8DA91634230A5D8324DBD4039F8376404AB1B7FF1B37DF63D22AFB2B6ABE37B31E8276B28427FA56FCF38EDF05FBC1EEF50C81A1C4F88560048D1C0E6D20B13000B384E0AE3AFED2751927F
CERTIFICATE:8030000000F0308201BD30820167A003020102020500B7D56095300D06092A864886F70D01010505003064310B3009060355040613024245310D300B06035504070C0447656E7431193017060355040A0C104B61486F2053696E742D4C696576656E31143012060355040B0C0B56616B67726F65702049543115301306035504030C0C4A616E20566F7373616572743020170D3130303232343039343330325A180F35313739303130393139323934325A3064310B3009060355040613024245310D300B06035504070C0447656E7431193017060355040A0C104B61486F2053696E742D4C696576656E31143012060355040B0C0B56
Exception in thread "main" java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:110)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
    at be.msec.client.Client.main(Client.java:133)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Empty input
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:106)
    ... 2 more
```

Is it possible that my approach to sending the certificate to the host application is wrong? Also, could I be retreiving the certficate in the host application in a wrong way? I could not get my solution here: [Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input X509Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275509/could-not-parse-certificate-java-io-ioexception-empty-input-x509certificate)

Comment: The code is incomplete. Please include all the code that defines and uses `resp2` in point 4, which is where the exception is actually thrown.

Comment: That was supposed to be resp4. I have just changed it and now I get a certificate with a reasonable length printed out. However, the error still persists.

Comment: I still see another `resp2` in your code. Is that also a mistake? You should isolate your code into small methods to avoid this kind of wrong variable error at compile time.

Comment: Oopse! changed that to resp3. And the error is still there.